Find value pairs matching multiple ratios in array
Google Apps Script:
I have an array with numbers. The array contains monetary values extracted from an invoice. Another array contains the applicable VAT/tax values.
For each tax value I want to find the applicable value pair(s) in the array.
Example input:

Resulting Input Arrays:
values = [4000, 2500, 2066.12, 2000, 1834.86];
taxRates = [9,21];

The desired output from these inputs would be:
taxAmounts = [[2000,2500][1834.86, 2066,12]];

indicated in the image above in colors where the numbers in the output came from;
 taxAmounts[0][0] = 2000    = green  = inc tax amount (for taxRates[0])
 taxAmounts[1][0] = 1834.86 = brown  = ex tax amount (for taxRates[0])
 taxAmounts[0][1] = 2500    = yellow = inc tax amount (for taxRates[1])
 taxAmounts[1][1] = 2066,12 = pink   = ex tax amount (for taxRates[1])

in other words I want to find the following values:
inc tax amount for each taxRate in 'taxRates'
ex tax amount for each taxRate in 'taxRates'

My approach:(pseudo code)
Look for 2 items in array which differ by 21%
     when found, check if the highest of these 2 numbers is the highest number in the array
         if highest number --> return this number     //if highest number then only 1 tax bracket
         if not highest number                        //multiple tax brackets
             check for matching value pair for next item in 'taxRates' Array (recursion)
                 if number found in 1st check + number found in 2nd check = highest number in array --> 
                    return these 2 numbers
                 else
                    continue checking for lower % values e.g. 104% until...
                    ...sum of all found values == highest num in array, then return these numbers
                       if no satisfactory match found after all checks
                           return undefined;

I have tried to write this in code but not getting correct output so must have made an error in my code which I thus far have not been able to fix. Most likely there is a much smarter way to write this.
My code:
function findBtwPairs(btwRates, amountsArr, incBtwArr, exBtwArr){
  for(m=0 ; m < btwRates.length ; m++){
    skipIndex = 0;
    for (i=0;i<amountsArr.length;i++){
      for (j=0;j<amountsArr.length;j++){
        if (i!=j){
          cond1 = (roundTo((amountsArr[i]/amountsArr[j]),2) == (1+btwRates[m]/100));
            cond2 = (roundTo((amountsArr[i]/amountsArr[j]),2) == (btwRates[m]/100));
          if (cond1 || cond2){          //inc btw and ex btw specified
              if(cond1){incBtw = amountsArr[i]; exBtw = amountsArr[j];}else{incBtw = amountsArr[i]+amountsArr[j]; exBtw = amountsArr[j];};
            if(roundTo(incBtw,0) == roundTo(amountsArr[0],0)){              //if found amount is highest number
              return [[incBtw], [exBtw]];
            }else{                      //if found amount NOT highest number
                incBtwArr = [incBtw]; exBtw = [exBtw];      //convert to arrays
              functionOutput = findBtwPairs(btwRates, amountsArr, incBtw, exBtw);
              if(functionOutput != undefined){
                incBtwArr = incBtwArr + functionOutput[0]; console.log("functionOutput[0] =" + functionOutput[0]);
                exBtwArr = exBtwArr + functionOutput[1]; console.log("functionOutput[1] =" + functionOutput[0]);
                }           //add found inc. and ex. btw values (e.g. 9% inc/ex value) to 'incBtw' and 'exBtw' Arrays
              if (roundTo(sumArray(incBtwArr),0) == roundTo(amountsArr[0]),0){
                return [incBtwArr, exBtwArr]
                }
              } // end of if/else
            } // end of if(cond1 || cond2){
          } // end of if (i!=j){
        } // end of j loop
      } // end of i loop
    } //end of m loop
    console.log( "BTW RATES NOT FOUND USING RATES IN 'btwRates' Array" );
  } // end of fn 'findBtwPairs'

//$$ Helper functions $$

function sumArray(array){
    return array.reduce(add, 0); // with initial value to avoid when the array is empty
    }

function add(accumulator, a) {
  return accumulator + a;
}

function roundTo(num, decimals) {
  return ( +num.toFixed(decimals));
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. You want to achieve from Resulting Input Arrays: to The desired output from these inputs would be:. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I cannot understand the relationship between those input and output values and my code: and inc tax amount for each taxRate in 'taxRates' and ex tax amount for each taxRate in 'taxRates'. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike thank you. I have since edited my code (see answer underneath) in a better way. It almost works perfectly. There is perhaps something you could help me with;
In the 3rd line of code of the function 'theBtwFinder' i do a comparison using the function 'sumArray' and 'roundTo' . However it seems like sumArray does not return a number value in this line of code. When in line 1 of 'tester' function it does work properly. Any ideas why this might be the case?
Comparison should be true when sum of all valuess in valuePairs arr == amounts[0] which is the case with my test values..

@Tanaike Regarding question in previous comment: I made a logic Error; i was adding all values in the 'valuePairs' array together when I should only add the amounts including BTW (even indices). Therefore I never got to the correct value/my comparison was incorrect. will edit code in answer soon.

I hope this can help
function findBtwPairs(taxRates, values) {
    let taxAmounts = [];

    for (let rate of taxRates) {
        let found = false;

        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
                let exTax = values[j];
                let incTax = values[i] - exTax;

                if (Math.abs(incTax / exTax * 100 - rate) < 0.01) {
                    taxAmounts.push([values[i], exTax]);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) break;
        }
    }
    return taxAmounts;
}

// Example usage:
let values = [4000, 2500, 2066.12, 2000, 1834.86];
let taxRates = [9, 21];
let result = findBtwPairs(taxRates, values);
console.log(result);


I have since re-written my code in a better way;
my new code:
        var valuePairs = [];
var inc; var ex;
var amounts = [ 5000, 2000, 2000, 1834.86, 1652.89, 1000, 961.5385, 15, 12,3,1];
var btwTypes = [21,13,9,4];

function tester(){
  // console.log(roundTo(5000,0));
  console.log("final output = [" + theBtwFinder(btwTypes) + "]");
}

function theBtwFinder(rates){
  while(rates.length>0){
    if (findValuePair(rates[0]) != undefined){
      valuePairs.push(findValuePair(rates[0])[0]); valuePairs.push(findValuePair(rates[0])[1])

      if(roundTo(sumArrayEvenIndices(valuePairs),0) == roundTo(amounts[0],0)){
      return valuePairs;
      }
      }
      btwTypes.shift(); //remove first item of 'btwTypes' Array since we're done checking for that btw percentage
    }
  }

function findValuePair(deltaPercentage){
  for(i=0;i<amounts.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<amounts.length;j++){
      if(i!=j){ //don't check value against itself
        if ( roundTo(amounts[i]/amounts[j], 2) == (1 + deltaPercentage/100) ){
          inc = amounts[i]; ex = amounts[j];
          return[inc, ex];
        }else if( roundTo(amounts[i]/amounts[j], 2) == (deltaPercentage/100) ){
          inc = amounts[i]+amounts[j]; ex = amounts[j];
          return[inc, ex];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined; //no pair found
}

// $$$ HELPER FUNCTIONS $$$
function sumArrayEvenIndices(array){
  var sum = 0;
  for(index in array){
    if (!(index % 2)){ //of index is even
      sum += array[index];
    }
  }
    return sum; 
    }

function roundTo(num, decimals) {
  return ( +num.toFixed(decimals));
}

Visual representation of what the code does:
function input:


How does this answer the question?

@wicket the code in the above answer takes the example inputs in my question (montery values) and return the desired amounts (inc. and ex. tax amounts for the different specified tax brackets). hence answering my original question (how to change the code such that it produces the desired output values.
